# Microphone is playing back my internal audio Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, audio-recording, pavucontrol

There's a problem with my input device (internal mic), is getting my internal audio instead of external source. When I play music or any audio the input values move like showed in the linked image below:

[image]

I have this configured with `pavucontrol`:

[image]

I've tried changing the device configuration, settings, values, etc. I suspect of a screen recording software (kazam) that I used that might have changed my config or enabled some audio mod for playing back internal audio on mic.

PD: This is not a noise or feedback problem, my microphone is playing back my internal audio.

I don't know what else to try at this point.

EDIT:

Output of `pactl list short sources`

```
angel@angel-ubuntu  ~  pactl list short sources
0   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
1   alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
```

Output of `pactl list short modules`

```
 angel@angel-ubuntu  ~  pactl list short modules
0   module-device-restore       
1   module-stream-restore       
2   module-card-restore     
3   module-augment-properties       
4   module-switch-on-port-available     
5   module-udev-detect      
6   module-alsa-card    device_id="0" name="pci-0000_00_1f.3" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"    
7   module-bluetooth-policy     
8   module-bluetooth-discover       
9   module-bluez5-discover      
10  module-native-protocol-unix     
11  module-default-device-restore       
12  module-rescue-streams       
13  module-always-sink      
14  module-intended-roles       
15  module-suspend-on-idle      
16  module-systemd-login        
17  module-position-event-sounds        
18  module-filter-heuristics        
19  module-filter-apply     
20  module-x11-publish  display=:0  
21  module-x11-bell display=:0 sample=bell.ogg  
22  module-x11-cork-request display=:0  
23  module-x11-xsmp display=:0 session_manager=local/angel-ubuntu:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2852,unix/angel-ubuntu:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2852
```

Comment: In future you can make most programs print English messages by prefixing the command with `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX`, e. g. `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX free`. Works the same for graphical applications. With super-user privileges you need `sudo LC_MESSAGES=POSIX apt ...` or `gksudo env LC_MESSAGES=POSIX synaptic` (for graphical applications).

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `pactl list short sources` and `pactl list short modules`? Thanks.